# Can I consume the angular2 in-memory-web api with Postman?

Tags: angular, postman, angular2-observables

When I consume the in-memory-web-api with Postman I get a `404: Cannot GET /api/friends`. My Angular2 application is consuming the same service and it is working correctly, so the service is not the issue I guess. Probably the in-memory-web-api cannot be consumed from Postman.

**My in-memory-web API:**

```
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
    createDb() {
        let friends = [
            { id: 11, name: 'Felipe' },
            { id: 12, name: 'Camila' },
            { id: 13, name: 'Andres' },
            { id: 14, name: 'Camilo' },
            { id: 15, name: 'Tito' }
        ];
        return { friends };
    }
}
```

**Service:**

```
import { Observable, Operator } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import { Friend } from './friend.model';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http'

@Injectable()
export class FriendsService {
    private friendsUrl = 'api/friends';
    private headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getFriends(): Observable<Friend[]> {
        const frienList = this.http.get(this.friendsUrl);
        return frienList.map((r: Response) => r.json().data as Friend[])
    }
    ...
```

**Component:**

```
import { Friend } from './friend.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { FriendsService } from './friends.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  friends: Observable<Friend[]>;

  constructor(private friendService: FriendsService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.friends = this.friendService.getFriends();
  }
  ...
```

**Postman Screenshot:**
[image]

Comment: No, you can't - it intercepts the requests in the Angular backend, it's not actually running a web server.

Comment: ... as it says in the second line of the repository readme.
https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api

Comment: Yes , as @jonrsharpe said , it seem like Angular intercepts the request on the backend , if you check the network trace on the browser when you install it on Angular app there is no outgoing http requests and it running fine use Anguler HttpClient.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about Angular an the in-memory API server, obviously your browser cannot even be reached let alone respond to incoming HTTP requests from Postman or anything else. You're confusing browsers and HTTP servers.